# How can I ensure that availability calendar only show one month at a time?

Tags: theming, datetime

I'm displaying a calendar on a basic page and I have specified that I want the monthly views to show only 1 at a time.  1 per col / 1 per row.

For some reason 3 are displayed.

my calendar can be seen at seosolutions.london

[image]
[image]

How can I only display 1 month at a time? can I hard code this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found a css fix for this:

availability_calendar.base.css

adding

.cal-viewport { width: 220px !important; }